# Flutter BottomNavigationBar remove default paddings

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am using `BottomNavigationBar` with icon and label property. Now I want remove icon top and label bottom paddings. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove default padding or margin on Bottom Navigation Bar from Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62665826/remove-default-padding-or-margin-on-bottom-navigation-bar-from-flutter)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this solution not work for me